# pypy3 import psycopg2 error (undefined symbol: PyCoder_Encoder)

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, pypy

I installed psycopg2 to pypy3(Python3.5.3) by the following code on Ubuntu16.04:

```
pypy3 -m pip install psycopg2
```

However, I got some errors:

> Error：b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-epd368s6/psycopg2

And I found the solution in "[You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253681/you-need-to-install-postgresql-server-dev-x-y-for-building-a-server-side-extensi)".

My computer has already installed Postgresql9.5, so I used these commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
pypy3 -m pip install psycopg2
```

No error was reported, but when I tried "import psycopg2", I got ImportError:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP5NZ.png)

I found the same error in "[pypy3 import psycopg2 error (PyCodec_Encoder)](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2766/pypy3-import-psycopg2-error)", but I did not found a solution.

Do someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

The PyPy issue you [pointed to](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2766/pypy3-import-psycopg2-error) contains the answer "Someone will have to implement the missing function (and the other missing PyCodec_* functions. Currently we only implement very few in [codec.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/py3.5/pypy/module/cpyext/codecs.py). The implementation is quite straight-forward based on the pattern in the functions implemented, the harder part is writing tests.

There is the [psycopg2cffi package](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2cffi), which should work on PyPy and will be faster. Perhaps give it a try and comment here if it serves your needs.

Comment: pscopg2cffi with its compat module to make it masquerade as psycopg2 was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

psycopg2-binary works with latest version of PyPy 3.6 (nightly build from 2020-01-23) as it contains the PyCodec_Encoder and PyCodec_Decoder implementations.

Comment: Great suggestion, this fixed "undefined symbol: timeradd" error for me.