# how to install pyscopg2 on kali-linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to install pyscopg2 on kali-linux 
after installing postgresql I tried :

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyscopg2
```

and I get the following :

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_hg2dt6y/psycopg2/
```

1)
I tried :

```
$ sudo pip3 install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y
```

and I get the following :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement postgresql-server-dev-X.Y (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for postgresql-server-dev-X.Y
```

I expect pyscopg2 to be installed .

Comment: X.Y is a placeholder...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253681/you-need-to-install-postgresql-server-dev-x-y-for-building-a-server-side-extensi)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18,
install the dependency first -

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python3-dev
```

And then go to your environment and install -

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```